# Homebrew: Could not symlink, /usr/local/share/man/man7 is not writable

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

I'm installing LightGBM on OSX, following the [installation guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/wiki/Installation-Guide). While installing cmake, `Homebrew` gives such warning message:

```
Warning: cmake-3.8.1 already installed, it's just not linked.
```

Then I try:

```
$brew link cmake
```

it gives:

```
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.1...
Error: Could not symlink share/man/man7/cmake-buildsystem.7
/usr/local/share/man/man7 is not writable.
```

Comment: Did you try with sudo? :)

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/share/man`

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The proposition of Mark Setchell to use `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/share/man` is right. According to the [Homebrew troubleshooting page](http://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting.html):

> If commands fail with permissions errors, check the permissions of /usr/local’s subdirectories. If you’re unsure what to do, you can run `cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var Frameworks`

but the proposition of Nano to use `sudo` is not a good one. According to the [Homebrew FAQ](http://docs.brew.sh/FAQ.html):

> **Homebrew is designed to work without using sudo**. You can decide to use it but **we strongly recommend not to do so**. If you have used sudo and run into a bug then this is likely to be the cause. Please don’t file a bug report unless you can reproduce it after reinstalling Homebrew from scratch without using sudo.

Answer (score 9):

Just follow these 4 steps

1. `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*`
2. `brew doctor`
3. `brew prune`
4. `brew link cmake`