# brew link php71: Could not symlink sbin/php-fpm

Tags: php, laravel, homebrew, laravel-valet

I'm trying to install Laravel Valet, which requires php 7.1, but when i run brew install php71, I get the following error:

```
==> Pouring php71-7.1.10_21.high_sierra.bottle.tar.gz
Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink sbin/php-fpm
/usr/local/sbin is not writable.
```

I get the same error when i run `brew link php71`. If i run `php -v`, I actually see that I'm currently running PHP 7.1.7.

But when I run valet install, I get:

```
  [DomainException]
  Unable to determine linked PHP.
```

I don't even have an sbin directory in /usr/local.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a guess but you probably need to temporarily disable *"System Integrity Protection"*... `csrutil` or somesuch.

Comment: That did not make the sbin directory appear.

Comment: You should be able to make it yourself and try again `mkdir /usr/local/sbin`

Comment: Ok that worked! Not sure I feel good about it, but installing nonetheless.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I solved this problem by first creating the directory `sbin`:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/sbin
```

then if you are like me using macOS highSierra 10+ you need to run:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/sbin
```

after this

```
brew link php
```

Comment: When you say "local dir" do you mean `/usr/local/sbin`?

Comment: This is one of the best explanations by far, thanks. @AndyIbanez it is, indeed

Comment: ```sudo mkdir /usr/local/sbin``` after ```sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/sbin``` and just ```brew link php```

Comment: This solution is worked for me. I was having a problem linking brew to php. The error was permission denied @ apply2files.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Laravel Valet, I had a similar issue with sbin not being writable. I had to make the directory, then utilized the solution included at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44195496/homebrew-could-not-symlink-usr-local-share-man-man7-is-not-writable). This finally allowed me the proper permissions to run a brew link command with a previously installed version of php 7.1.

Comment: Just for future reference, it's typically best practice to include the relevant part of the link in your answer just in case the page or question/answer are deleted. That way this question and your answer remain intact and valid.

Comment: I didn't get this.