# Can't install laravel installer via composer on MAC (catalina)

Tags: php, laravel, macos

I am being asked to install PHP extension. I've used brew install php@7.3 it updated but has not satisfied the requirements. What do i need to do to satisfy the requirements?

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.2.0].
    - laravel/installer v2.2.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
```

I've tried the suggestions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290566/install-ext-zip-for-mac) and it did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778133/brew-link-php71-could-not-symlink-sbin-php-fpm).

"I solved this problem by first creating a new dir sbin in the local dir:

```
sudo mkdir sbin
```

then if you are like me using macOS highSierra 10+ you need to run:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)
```

after this

```
brew link php
```

"