# Switch of php versions not working on mac

Tags: php, homebrew

I have High Sierra installed and it comes with php 7.1. During the environment I ended up being able to upgrade to php7.2 but wasn't able to document it, so I dont exactly know what I did. Now, I am trying to switch to php 7.3

Using brew, I ran the following commands:

```
brew unlink php@7.2

brew services install php@7.3

brew link php@7.3
```

If I restart my terminal and check for the php version:

```
php -v
```

I still see 7.2.25 version and not 7.3 as I desire

I also tried with a node package that I found in this link [here](https://medium.com/@jalendport/how-to-switch-between-php-versions-on-your-mac-b561758ed8f5) but no success.

How do I successfully switch between php versions?

Comment: Actually it is possible to have multiple PHP versions installed and switch between them. Not sure what exactly wrong in your case, but take a look at the article, maybe it will give you some clues: http://hexlator.blogspot.com/2018/04/macos-1013-high-sierra-apache-setup_14.html

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here is my installation script:

- `brew install php@7.2`
- `brew link --force php@7.2`
- `brew services start php@7.2`
- `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"`
- `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/sbin:$PATH"`

Now my output would be as:

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.2.25 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2019 10:27:28) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.25, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

I think the `PATH` environment setup is something matters. And it does show in instructions as part of the installation process though.

Hope it helps resolving your issue.

Comment: in my terminal it's showing the updated version but  php is not working at all

Comment: close your terminal and reopen terminal and check by php -v

Comment: I had errors for the first 3 above and finally the export path fixed it!

Answer (score 8):

Since I had to face this issue as well, let me share how to make this work.
If you have to switch back and forth on mac then this is what works for me.

Let's say you have multiple PHP versions installed 7.2 and 7.4

[image: Services List and Current version]

Now my current PHP version is 7.4 & I have to switch back to 7.2, steps will be.

1. `brew unlink php@7.4 && brew link php@7.2 --force`
2. `nano ~/.zshrc -> Update Export Path From 7.4 to 7.2`

   [image: zshrc file]
3. Save It.
4. `brew services stop php@7.4`
5. `brew services start php@7.2`

[image]

Voila.
To go back to 7.4 Run `brew unlink php@7.2 && brew link php@7.4 --force` & uncomment export files. That's it.

Answer (score 6):

Until I restarted Terminal I kept seeing the old version.

Answer (score 5):

Open the terminal then run

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

In the file that you open, you'll find the exported path of PHP as follows:

```
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.2/sbin:$PATH"
```

Then comment the old version by adding `#` at the first of line and save file `CTRL+x`

after that close the terminal or open new one then get the php version again

```
php --version
```

I hope you have completely switched to the new PHP version

Answer (score 1):

here is my approach to switch between php7.3 and php 8.2 and want to use 8.2

- brew install php@8.2
- brew unlink php@7.3
- brew link php@8.2
- php -v
  now my output will be like this

> PHP 7.3.33 (cli) (built: Jul 13 2023 17:29:11) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
> 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.3.33, Copyright (c) 1998-2018
> Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v7.3.33, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

we can change to php 7.3 by this steps

- brew unlink php@8.2
- brew link php@7.3
- php -v

> PHP 8.2.10 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2023 18:52:55) (NTS) Copyright (c) The
> PHP Group Zend Engine v4.2.10, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.2.10, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

@chenrui's is perfect. I just had to create the **sbin** directory additionally as well.

You can find it [question]: [brew link php71: Could not symlink sbin/php-fpm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778133/brew-link-php71-could-not-symlink-sbin-php-fpm)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to do the following steps. I was using MAMP and brew for php.

1. Match PHP Versions:

Ensure that the PHP version used in your terminal matches the one used by MAMP. You can set the terminal to use MAMP's PHP by adding MAMP's PHP to your PATH.
First, find out which PHP version MAMP is using by checking in MAMP's preferences.

Then, add MAMP's PHP to your PATH by editing your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc`, or `~/.bashrc` (depending on your shell) with something like:
`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php[x.x.x]/bin:$PATH`

Replace **[x.x.x]** with the PHP version that you are using.

After editing, save the file and run source `~/.bash_profile`, source `~/.zshrc`, or source `~/.bashrc`.

2. Configure MySQL Connection:

In your .env file for the Laravel project, ensure that the MySQL connection details are set to match your systems MySQL settings. For me the default MySQL runs on port 8889, and the default username is root with the password root.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

3. Start MAMP Servers:

Make sure both Apache and MySQL servers in MAMP are running.

4. Check MySQL Socket:

In my case I was using Laravel, which might be trying to use the default MySQL socket instead of the one used by MAMP. Update the DB_SOCKET in your **.env** file with MAMP’s MySQL socket path, typically:
`DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

5. Clear Configuration Cache:

Run `php artisan config:clear` to clear Laravel's configuration cache. I also like to run `php artisan optimize`.

6. Restart Terminal:

After making changes to configuration files or environment variables, restart your terminal to ensure the changes take effect.

Finally I tested the PHP and MySQL Connection:

Verify that PHP and MySQL are working correctly in your terminal by running simple test commands like ``` php -v`` for PHP version and ``mysql --version ``` for MySQL version.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily switch between any number of PHP versions on MacOS.
I had the same problem while switching between PHP 7.4 and 8.3.
Just follow the steps mentioned below and you are ready to go.

First install the PHP versions you need. If you've already installed it, you can skip this step or it'll tell you that the version is already installed.

```
brew install php@7.4
brew install php@8.3
```

Now if you are using the default terminal on macOS, you'll use **/~.bash_profile** but if you are using zsh terminal, use **/~.zshrc**

```
sudo nano /~.zshrc
```

Add these lines at the end of that file

```
# Add PHP 7.4 paths
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"

# Add PHP 8.3 paths
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.3/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.3/sbin:$PATH"

# Aliases
alias usephp8='brew unlink php@7.4 && brew link --overwrite --force php@8.3 && export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.3/bin:$PATH" && export
PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@8.3/sbin:$PATH"'
alias usephp7='brew unlink php@8.3 && brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4 && export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH" && export
PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"'
```

Now run this command

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

To switch between php8.3 and php7.4, use these aliases

```
usephp7
usephp8
```

You can also run a PHP project at localhost without installing XAMPP. Open terminal and go to the project path and run this command

```
php -S localhost:8000
```