# Update PHP to 7.4 macOS Catalina with brew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, php-7.4

I try to update my PHP version to `7.4` on macOS Catalina with brew.

I did `brew install php@7.4`

If I check my version `php -v`, I still see the old version `PHP 7.3.11`?

What do I have to do?

**Update:**

After `brew doctor` I get:

> Warning: Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have
> installed formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin. Consider
> setting the PATH for example like so:   echo 'export
> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile

Comment: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/export-path-issues-for-macos/7732/3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

try:

```
brew update
brew upgrade php
php -v
brew services start php
```

or

```
brew services restart php
```

if you use apache server:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

if you use ngnix

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

**Edit:**

```
brew unlink php@7.3
brew link php@7.4
```

Comment: thanks but after trying above, it still show PHP 7.3.11? I need to update to 7.4 because of composer's dependencies.

Comment: @meez. after services restart ?

Comment: After `brew unlink php@7.3` I get `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3` ?

Comment: @meez run brew doctor

Answer (score 194):

You can find my similar answer for [php@7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59150210/791609).

- `brew install php@7.4`
- `brew link --force --overwrite php@7.4`
- `brew services start php@7.4`
- `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"`
- `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"`

Comment: This solution works perfectly in MacOS BigSur.

Comment: Instead of link --force I had to do `brew link --overwrite php@7.4`

Comment: yeah, add `--overwrite` to the OP (it would consider the existing php links), thanks Jannie!

Comment: 96 upvotes is not enough! Thank you! Works on BigSur 11.4

Comment: I'm doing this in Catalina but `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"` seems to take forever.

Comment: it's good and working well on OSX Monterey

Comment: Works perfectly on macOS Catalina. Thanks.

Comment: Works on macOS 13

Comment: No, does not work in Catalina. First command returns `Error: php@7.4 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula!`. Next returns `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php@7.4`

Comment: Unfortunately 7.4 is no longer available on Homebrew — anyone know how else to install this version as I do need it?

Comment: probably due to my change, https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/153820, but it was disabled already long before though.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone want to downgrade php from latest 8.1.2 to 7.4 on systems demand, try the below commands with homebrew:
Installing PHP 7.4 :

```
brew install php@7.4
brew services restart php
brew unlink php@8.1
brew link php@7.4
```

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Or

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using terminal of MacOS. Don't use terminal in vscode.

Comment: Oddly enough, this did the trick even though I've linked/unlinked taps various times successfully from the VS Code terminal.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that PHP v7.4 is no longer available on the default Homebrew repository. However, you can add an additional Tap (repository) and still install it:

1. `brew tap shivammathur/php` ([Adds this repo](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php))
2. `brew install php@7.4`

(I think this qualifies as an answer)

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue, all the suggestion here didn't work until I ran:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then ran the command I was trying before and the error stopped, for my case it was php

dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openldap/lib/libldap-2.4.2.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin/php
Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      php -v

Answer (score 0):

1. I move to directory by: cd /usr/local
2. Find the file location by: find /usr/local/ -name libphp7.so. (Then get the file location at: /usr/local//Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.23/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so. I copy this.)
3. I open the file by: sudo vim /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
4. Look for the line by: /libphp7.so
5. Uncomment the line and update the line by: LoadModule php7_module /usr/local//Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.23/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
6. Restart apache by: sudo apachectl restart
7. Verify PHP by accessing http://localhost/phpinfo.php