# PHP Deprecated issue when running artisan command

Tags: php, composer-php, octobercms

Whenever I run an artisan command I am getting this issue.

I am using Valet and PHP 8.1. I have tried changing versions of PHP but I still get this issue.

When i run:

```
jakefeeley@Jakes-MBP marketing % php artisan plugin:install vojtasvoboda.twigextensions
```

Returns:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1231

Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1231
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1242

Deprecated: Return type of October\Rain\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/october/rain/src/Config/Repository.php on line 446
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of October\Rain\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/october/rain/src/Config/Repository.php on line 458

Deprecated: Return type of October\Rain\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/october/rain/src/Config/Repository.php on line 458
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of October\Rain\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/october/rain/src/Config/Repository.php on line 469

Deprecated: Return type of October\Rain\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/october/rain/src/Config/Repository.php on line 469
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1277
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of ...', '/Users/jakefeel...', 1277)
#1 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('/Users/jakefeel...')
#2 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Users/jakefeel...')
#3 

In Collection.php line 11:
                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset  
  ): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Col  
  lection.php:1277                                                                                                                                                                                       
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                           
  #0 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of   
  ...', '/Users/jakefeel...', 1277)                                                                                                                                                                      
  #1 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('/Users/jakefeel...')                                                                                       
  #2 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Users/jakefeel...')                                                                 
  #3 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/october/rain/src/Support/Collection.php(11): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')                                       
  #4 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(478): include('/Users/jakefeel...')                                                                                       
  #5 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(346): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Users/jakefeel...')                                                                 
  #6 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/october/rain/src/Support/helpers.php(269): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('October\\Rain\\Su...')                                        
  #7 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): collect(Array)                                                                
  #8 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')                      
  #9 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()                    
  #10 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(219): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(October\Rain  
  \Foundation\Application))                                                                                                                                                                              
  #11 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(320): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)                      
  #12 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()                            
  #13 /Users/jakefeeley/Sites/certhub/marketing/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\Co  
  nsoleOutput))                                                                                                                                                                                          
  #14 {main}
```

Comment: Does your dependencies also supports php 8.1?

Comment: which build/version of OctoberCMS you are using?

Comment: @HardikSatasiya we are using 2.11.2

Comment: The latest OctoberCMS seems to be using Laravel 6.0 which does not officially support PHP 8.1 (or even PHP 8.0). If you installed it using composer you should have received errors notifying you of this

Comment: @apokryfos it supports 7.4 but i get the same errors

Comment: according to your question you have PHP 8.1 which it does not support. That deprecation warning only exists in PHP 8.1 so if you tried different PHP versions and still got the same error then you didn't successfully switch PHP versions

Comment: can you please try checking it with PHP 8.0, as in my local I am using PHP 8.0.10 and plugin installed correctly, so it seems its PHP 8.1 may be

Answer (score 17):

In my experience this is due to attempting to run Laravel 7 (or earlier) under PHP 8.1. I know you said you tried changing PHP versions, but I would double-check that your changes definitely took effect.

For Laravel 7, switching back to PHP 8.0 fixed the issue for me.

nb: Laravel 7's `composer.json` incorrectly specifies `"php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",` which implies it *can* run under PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 13):

In my case, i had Laravel 8.12 then i got this error.
so i change `"laravel/framework": "^8.12",` to `"laravel/framework": "^8.75",` in Composer.json . then i ran `composer update` on terminal. there you go!

*at the end, when i ran `php artisan --version` my laravel version was 8.83.1

Comment: Thank you! This was precisely the issue with my setup!

Comment: For the record, you could also do `"laravel/framework": "^8.0"` to catch the latest version of 8.X.

Answer (score 6):

I ran composer update and it fixed things

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31089963)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when i update my php version from 7 to 8.
I updated "laravel/framework" to "^8.75" and ran composer update. That works for me.

Comment: This helped me my laravel version was "laravel/framework": "^8.0",  Changed it to "^8.75"  Solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I tried to run  **Laravel 7.3** on php 8.1

For me i had **2 versions** of php installed on my computer, `php-7.4 and php-8.1.`

When i checked the php version on the terminal, using `php --version`
the terminal showed me i was using php 7.4

So I thought php 7.4 was what laravel was using, But that was not the case. Somehow the web server (nginx) was redirecting to **php 8.1**

To know for sure which php version is being used, use the built-in phpinfo() method. Below is one way to do it

- backup index.php from your Laravel project
- Then remove everything from the index.php file

Add the following on index.php file

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

Then try to access your Laravel project.
That will give you **php information page** that will include the information about the version of php your Laravel project is actually using.

As I was using homebrew on macOS Big Sur, I used these commands to stop php8.1

```
brew services stop php@8.1
brew unlink php@8.1
```

Then I started php 7.4

```
brew services start php@7.4
brew link php@7.4
```

[For more info on switching php versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142504/switch-of-php-versions-not-working-on-mac)

Comment: Thanks dude for helping me I was having same error :)

Comment: Man you have just saved me from losing my mind. I wish I could upvote you more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issues due to the laravel/php versions, I was using laravel 6.X LTS and php 8.1 which is not compatible as you can check here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/releases so you have two choices either upgrade your laravel or downgrade your php, im my case I was using Homestead & Vagrant so in your `sites` entry of your Homestead.yaml you can do something like

```
sites:
    - map: your-site.local
      to: /home/vagrant/your-site/public
      php: "7.4"
```

Or any php version you want to use and run `vagrant reload --provision`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error whilre running my web app ( using laravel with php7.3 ) using homestead. It took me so long to finally found out that the error I got was from running php8 in the host machine.

So I change the php version from the host machine to 7.3 as well.

Now the problem has all gone.

I dont know why but apparently, the php in the host machine does affect the php in the homesteead as well.

So you need to make sure the php version in homestead is the same as the host machine.

Answer (score -3):

Find the file and add method header:

```
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function myFun() {
   [...]
}
```

[Documentation](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/ReturnTypeWillChange) & [Example](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/504)

Answer (score -5):

Try to check your dependences of composer.json and package.json, check if all dependences are in right place (for production->dependences not dependences-dev)