# Composer detected issues in your platform. PHP 8.1

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have problem with me app. When I run "composer install" I get error "**Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0**"."
On the PHP server there is **8.1.3**

The problem arose when I wanted to add a library "**vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq**"

[image]

Composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.3",
        "fabpot/goutte": "^4.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "illuminate/queue": "*",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.4",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Please checkout this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70245146/php-deprecated-issue-when-running-artisan-command/71202847#71202847

Answer (score 0):

PHP 8.1.12 works for me. It is the latest updated version. If you have multiple PHP Versions then enable the exact 8.1.12