# How do you change the php version that you don't want to? in MAC terminal

Tags: php, macos, terminal

Device macbook air 2017 os mojave

I want to replace PHP version 7.3.1 on my mac with 8.1.11 but don't want to be able to I've tried several sources but the result is the same. This is the source I used [Switch of php versions not working on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142504/switch-of-php-versions-not-working-on-mac)

Comment: Better post this question in superuser.com