# Cannot install homebrew packages because permission is denied

Tags: terminal, homebrew

When I run `brew install {package}`, I get the following:

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/{package}: Permission denied
```

But if I try to use `sudo brew install {package}`, I get the following:

```
Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
```

How do I get homebrew working again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix permissions for Homebrew by running:

```
cd /usr/local && sudo chown -R $(whoami) bin etc include lib sbin share var Frameworks
```

See this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208097/1807667

Comment: Be really, really careful running on command on mac! you're messing up with core files of the system!